# UICollectionViewCell change the background of the row cell (line)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

How to make a cell is selected  - change the background of the row cell (line)?
I do not know how to get the indexpath for row-line cell. One select cell changes color without any problems.
I need to change the background of the entire row. pls. help me

```
    Array *cellArray =  @[ @[@0, @0, @0, @2, @6, @0, @7, @0, @1],
                   @[@6, @8, @0, @0, @7, @0, @0, @9, @0],
                   @[@1, @9, @0, @0, @0, @4, @5, @0, @0],
                   @[@8, @2, @0, @1, @0, @0, @0, @4, @0],
                   @[@0, @0, @4, @6, @0, @2, @9, @0, @0],
                   @[@0, @5, @0, @0, @0, @3, @0, @2, @8],
                   @[@0, @0, @9, @3, @0, @0, @0, @7, @4],
                   @[@0, @4, @0, @0, @5, @0, @0, @3, @6],
                   @[@7, @0, @3, @0, @1, @8, @0, @0, @0]];
```

---

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

            //code

                    if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {

                            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

                            // set highlight color
                        } else {
                            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                            // set default color
                        }
```

---

```
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *arrayOfIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

    if (indexPath && [self.board isEditableFieldAtIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToReload = [@[indexPath] mutableCopy];
        if (self.indexPathForLastCellMarkedEditing && ![self.indexPathForLastCellMarkedEditing isEqual:indexPath]) {
           // if one cell was already marked, we have to unmark it
            [indexPathsToReload addObject:self.indexPathForLastCellMarkedEditing];
        }

        self.indexPathForLastCellMarkedEditing = indexPath;
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToReload];
    }
    else {
        [self unmarkCells];
    }

    self.indexPathForLastCellMarkedEditing = indexPath;
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPaths];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

---

[image](http://i017.radikal.ru/1404/fe/c737cb1583cf.png)

Comment: Your didSelectItemAtIndexPath ???????

Comment: Tis is CollectionView so you can change the colour of entire row...You only change background Colour of selected item.

Comment: yes, I use didSelectItemAtIndexPath, but I can change only one cell backgroundColor. How I get indexpatch for entire row?

Answer (score 0):

write this only

```
    if (cell.selected) 
     {
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // highlight selection 
     }
   else
     {
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // Default color
     }
```

Comment: Since color changes only clicked cell. I need that when you click on one of the cells in a line (row) - changed color from this line (row). How can I change the color of near by cells?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make each record in `cellArray` is a section and check on `[selectedIndexPath section]` then at `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` if the `[indexPath section]` is equal to `[selectedIndexPath section]` you can color all rows at this section

Good luck

Comment: In the final case, you should change the background lines vertically and horizontally at the intersection of the selected cell.